# Can't import module from ES 6 module which requires

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-modules, es6-modules

My module has `type` set as `module` in package.json, hence it is ES 6.

I need to import a module (which I do using `import`), but this module (`dexie-encrypted`) does `require` to a third module, therefor failing:

```
Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: Must use import to load ES Module: /Users/xxx/xxx/node_modules/dexie/dist/modern/dexie.mjs
    at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:329:5)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:970:11)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:813:14)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:996:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:92:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/xxx/xxx/node_modules/dexie-encrypted/dist/applyMiddleware.js:5:41)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1092:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1121:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:972:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:813:14) {
  code: 'ERR_REQUIRE_ESM'
}
```

How is a situation like this solved?

Comment: This is [issue #36](//github.com/mark43/dexie-encrypted/issues/36) on the GitHub repo.

Comment: To address the question in itself, you'll have to switch to full `require`s or use a transpiler like `babel` to be able to use an hybrid between `require`s and `import`s until the issue @SebastianSimon mentioned is resolved.